# Match lines of a file with headers in other to obtain entire para

Tags: bash, awk, perl

I want help with scripting to work with two files, wherein file 1 lists amino acids which are in specific order (one below the other and also might repeat) and the second file 2 constitutes the characteristics feature listed under each amino acid. Here, I am trying to match the amino acid from list one (file 1) to obtain its characteristics features listed under the same amino acid of the second file (file 2)and copy it to an output file in the same order as mentioned in file 1.

For example
File1.txt

```
    Threonine
    Glutamine
    Alanine
    Asparatate
    Glutamine
    Alanine
    Threonine
```

File2.txt

```
    [ Alanine ] 
    89.1    13.7    -3.12   -10.09
    [ Asparatate ]  
    133.1   30  -2.43   -10.35
    [ Glutamine ]   
    146.1   42.7    -3.46   -10.23
    [ Threonine ]   
    119.1   28.5    -2.43   -9.99
```

The output I am expecting is as below:
output.txt

```
    [ Threonine ]   
    119.1   28.5    -2.43   -9.99
    [ Glutamine ]   
    146.1   42.7    -3.46   -10.23
    [ Alanine ] 
    89.1    13.7    -3.12   -10.09
    [ Asparatate ]  
    133.1   30  -2.43   -10.35
    [ Glutamine ]   
    146.1   42.7    -3.46   -10.23
    [ Alanine ] 
    89.1    13.7    -3.12   -10.09 
    [ Threonine ]   
    119.1   28.5    -2.43   -9.99
```

I have tried using the below script in awk, which works with numbers as index other than words but not for this purpose.

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[ "\\[ " $1 " \\]" ]; next } /^\[/ { f=0 } { for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i) f=1 } f' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

I am not knowing how to modify the script to make it work on the words even. Please tell me where I am going wrong and help me execute the script to get the output as desired.

I will highly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Asha

Comment: Yes, the spaces has to be preserved. Also, file 1 is a list of amino acids, which has to find its match in second file to grep lines below it. Also, the order has to preserved as is in the file 1

Comment: only one word per line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything what you need to loop through acids in `File1.txt` and find matched line in `File2.txt` + 1 line which easy done by `grep`

```
for acid in $(sed 's/^\s*//' File1.txt)
do
    grep -FA1 "$acid" File2.txt
done > Output.txt
```

But if you like `awk`:

```
awk '
FNR!=NR{
    print "    [",$1,"]"
    print acids[$1]
    next
}
/\[/{
    acid=$2
    next
}
{
    acids[acid]=$0
}' File2.txt File1.txt > Output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first script has worked fine but awk script didnot generate the required output.

Comment: @Asha The second script is tested on your data (be attentive to pass secon file (with numbers) first).

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do this is using:

```
while read amino_acid
do
    grep -A1 ${amino_acid} File2.txt >> output.txt
done < File1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This has also worked to generate the output as required.

Answer (score 2):

With `xargs`/`grep`:

```
xargs -n1 -I '{}' grep '{}' -A1 File2.txt <File1.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `-n1`: forces xargs to execute the command for every line
- `-I '{}'`: set a placeholer
- `grep '{}' -A1 File2.txt`: the command to execute

  - `-A1`: print also the line after the search pattern
  - `File2.txt`: search trough `File2.txt`
- `<File1.txt`: input is `File1.txt`

Comment: Thanks, this script has also helped me in getting the required output